# facebook messenger m.me share link

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

I have a referral page with a modal where users can send a share link to their friends. I need to implement the following flow:

a user clicks on facebook messenger icon and their messenger opens up where the user can choose someone of their contacts to send a share link to.

Looks like this is a solution for me but I can't clarify some questions https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links/

1. I don't have an app and a page, I just need a user to open their messenger and paste and send a text to their friends.
2. Is this the same flow for web, iOS, Android?
3. Can I preload the text I want the user to share so that it will appear in the dialog with the contact the user has chosen (in some messengers it is possible)?

Answer (score 1):

FB has 2 different APIs for solving this issue: for web and for mobile. They are very similar and described here:

web https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog/
mobile https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/messenger/web

In two words, you need to add a FB script to activate FB JS SDK and then call a method to share a link.